# Linker error Unrar4iOS framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors, cocoapods, unrar

I have added Unrar4iOS framework and getting below linker error.
How to fix this?

```
duplicate symbol __Z12CallbackProcjlll in:
    /Users/dmitryvlasenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnrealReader-cpvucqqjfnkeppcasgjdrwasaryu/Build/Intermediates/UnrealReader.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnrealReader.build/Objects-normal/i386/Unrar4iOS.o
    /Users/dmitryvlasenko/Desktop/UnrealReader/Unrar4iOS.framework/Unrar4iOS(Unrar4iOS.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Unrar4iOS.header in:
    /Users/dmitryvlasenko/Desktop/UnrealReader/Unrar4iOS.framework/Unrar4iOS(Unrar4iOS.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Unrar4iOS._rarFile in:
    /Users/dmitryvlasenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnrealReader-cpvucqqjfnkeppcasgjdrwasaryu/Build/Intermediates/UnrealReader.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnrealReader.build/Objects-normal/i386/Unrar4iOS.o
    /Users/dmitryvlasenko/Desktop/UnrealReader/Unrar4iOS.framework/Unrar4iOS(Unrar4iOS.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Unrar4iOS.filename in:
  /Users/dmitryvlasenko/Desktop/UnrealReader/Unrar4iOS.framework/Unrar4iOS(RARExtractException.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_EHTYPE_$_RARExtractException in:
    /Users/dmitryvlasenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnrealReader-cpvucqqjfnkeppcasgjdrwasaryu/Build/Intermediates/UnrealReader.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnrealReader.build/Objects-normal/i386/RARExtractException.o
    /Users/dmitryvlasenko/Desktop/UnrealReader/Unrar4iOS.framework/Unrar4iOS(RARExtractException.o)
ld: 12 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates to you that Unrar4iOS is both defined in Unrar4iOS.a and as individual file in your project.
So go to:

TargetSettings->Build Phases->Link Binary with Libraries and remove the Unrar4iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have added the same library twice thats why it says "duplicate symbol __Z12CallbackProcjlll "

Answer (score 0):

The Unrar library is written in C++. If you don't have any .mm files in your project, then Xcode doesn't link against the C++ standard library, and all the references to C++ fail to link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a compiled test well framework:  [Unrar4iOS.framework](http://zhouzuyuan.cn/unrar.html)